# decide for what $n \in \mathbb{N}: 3^n \equiv n \mod 13$ is valid.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is not enough to try every option mod 13
because

- 3^1≡1 (mod 13) not true
- 3^2≡2 (mod 13) not true
- 3^3≡3 (mod 13) not true
- 3^4≡4 (mod 13) not true
- 3^5≡5 (mod 13) not true
- 3^6≡6 (mod 13) not true
- 3^7≡7 (mod 13) not true
- 3^8≡8 (mod 13) not true
- 3^9≡9 (mod 13) not true
- 3^10≡10 (mod 13) not true
- 3^11≡11 (mod 13) not true
- 3^12≡12 (mod 13) not true
- 3^13≡0 (mod 13) not true (a^(prime number)≡a(mod (prime number)

I dont know how to find those numbers, there is no repetition...

Comment: You only need consider the $n$ upto $12\cdot 13$ beause the exponent in $3^n$ can be reduced mod $12$. Then, you have all solutions modulo $12\cdot 13$

Comment: For all $k$ you have $3^{3k}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$,  $3^{3k+1}\equiv 3\pmod{13}$ and $3^{3k+2}\equiv 9\pmod{13}$, so the question becomes which number(s) are such that they satisfy $n\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ and $n\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ or are such that they satisfy $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $n\equiv 3\pmod{13}$ or are such that they satisfy $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ and $n\equiv 9\pmod{13}$.  Each of these can be found via chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: As far as looking all the way up to $12\cdot 13$, for the general problem perhaps such as if we were looking for $n$ such that $5^n\equiv n\pmod{13}$, but you can get away with only going up to $3\cdot 13$ since $3\mid 13-1$.  That being said... trying each outcome manually is a terrible idea that does not generalize well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

In the multiplicative group $(\mathbf Z/13\bf Z)^{\times}$, the element  $3$ has order $3$, hence $3^n\equiv3^{n\bmod 3}\mod 13$, and there are three cases

- If $n\equiv 0\mod 3$, $3^n\equiv 1\mod 13$;
- If $n\equiv 1\mod 3$,  $3^n\equiv 3\mod 13$;
- If $n\equiv 2\mod 3$,  $3^n\equiv 9\mod 13$.

Therefore, we have to solve the systems of congruences
$$ \begin{cases}
n\equiv a\mod 3, \\n\equiv b\mod 13,
\end{cases}\qquad (a,b)\in\bigl\{(0,1),(1,3),(2,9)\bigr\}.$$
You can use  the inverse of the isomorphism of the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/39\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z \times\mathbf Z/13\bf Z\\
n\bmod 39&\longmapsto (n\bmod 3, n\bmod 13)
\end{align}
This isomorphism uses a Bézout's relation: $3u+13v=1$ and is defined thus
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z \times\mathbf Z/13\bf Z&\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/39\mathbf Z,\\
(a\bmod 3, b\bmod 13)&\longmapsto 3ub+3va\bmod 39.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I try to show some results numerically:

$3^3\equiv 1\ mod (13)$

⇒$3^4\equiv 3 \ mod (13) $

⇒$3^{16}\equiv 3^4 \ mod (13)\equiv 3 \ mod (13)\equiv (13+3=16) \ mod (13) $

In this case $n=16$

$3^{29}=3^{16}\times 3^{13}\equiv (16\times 3=48) \ mod (13)\equiv 9 \ mod (13) $

⇒ $\frac {3^{29}}{3^2}=3^{27} \equiv 1  \ mod (13)\equiv (2\times 13 +1=27) \ mod (13)$

Or you may simply argue:

$(3^3)^3=3^{27}\equiv 1 \ mod (13)\equiv 27 \ mod (13)$

in this case $n=27$

I found by python $n= 16, 27, 35, 55, 66 , \cdot\cdot\cdot$

You can justify all these by similar argument.